# Identify integer, string and floating point literals

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python and I am stuck with a problem. I have an input file which contains data as below:

```
12345    67890     afghe
abcde    23456     0abcd
34567    __fred01  45678
123.456  12345a    123.
.456     ab00cd    00ab00
```

By using regular expression is need to parse each literal and classify whether the literal is a string or an integer or a floating point.
The code snippet is somewhat like below:

```
def processtoken(token):
    #Replace the following line with your code to classify
    # the string in 'token' according to your three Regular
    # Expressions and print the appropriate message.
    print('Inside Process Token')

    match = re.search(r'(0|[1-9][0-9]*|0[oO]?[0-7]+|0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+|0[bB][01]+)[lL]?', token)
    matchfp = re.search(r'^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+$',token)
    if match:
        print(match.group(),'matches INT')
    elif matchfp:
        print(matchfp.group(),'matches FP')
```

My issue is how can I structure the code to validate multiple regex conditions for each token passed. As of now the floating point if the condition is not validated. I want to check the token for, first integer regex if it matches or if it matches floating point regex or it matches string.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you insist on using regex to match numeric literals, see docs for complete list - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure the problem as follows:

```
integer_regex = r"^...$"
float_regex = r"^...$"
string_regex = r"^...$"

def processToken(token):

    if re.search(integer_regex, token):
        print(token, 'matches INT')
    elif re.search(float_regex, token):
        print(token, 'matches FLOAT')
    elif re.search(string_regex, token):
        print(token, 'matches STR')
    else:
        print(token, 'unknown')
```

Filling your patterns into the `*_regex` variables above.

Also note, your `float` pattern is no good, as it also matches `int`:

```
r'^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+$'
```

Since the decimal point is optional.  You might be better off breaking the pattern into an alternation with three options, starts with '.', ends with '.' or contains a '.' between numbers.  Also, in your integer pattern, the '?' in the octal section is incorrect:

```
0[oO]?[0-7]+
```

at this point we're trying to commit to octal so the prefix is not optional:

```
0[oO][0-7]+
```

You got this correct for hex and binary.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs on the code structure. I changed my code as below.But still only the first If is evaluated.import reimport sys
integer_regex = r"(0|[1-9][0-9]*|0[oO][0-7]+|0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+|0[bB][01]+)[lL]?" floating_regex = r"[+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?"
string_regex = r"(_|a-z|A-Z)(_|a-z|A-Z|0-9)" def processtoken(token):
if re.search(integer_regex, token):  print(token, 'matches INT')if re.search(floating_regex, token):  print(token,'matches FP') elif re.search(string_regex, token):
        print(token,'matched ID')
    else:
        print(token,'Does Not Match')

Comment: Please can you help

Comment: @np05, you left off the start and end anchors on your patterns which are requred when matching in this manner: r"^...$"  also your string pattern is missing its brackets: r"^(_|[a-z]|[A-Z])(_|[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*$" and as currently defined, nothing matches "0abcd" since you're saying strings can't begin with digits and there is no "0a" integer form.  Your floating point pattern is close but needs some work but make the changes I just suggested and see what still doesn't match.

Comment: thank you again for the inputs.I am pasting the output as below:processing tokens from inputdata.txt ...
12345 matches INT
67890 matches INT
afghe Does Not Match
abcde Does Not Match
23456 matches INT
0abcd matches INT
34567 matches INT
__fred01 matches INT
45678 matches INT
123.456 matches INT
12345a matches INT
123. matches INT
.456 matches INT
ab00cd matches INT
00ab00 matches INT and the code is as below:

Comment: import re
import sys
integer_regex = r"^(0|[1-9][0-9]*|0[oO][0-7]+|0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+|0[bB][01]+)[lL]?*$"
#integer_regex = r"(0|[1-9][0-9])"
floating_regex = r"[+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?"
string_regex = r"^(_|a-z|A-Z)(_|a-z|A-Z|0-9)*$"def processtoken(token):
    if re.search(integer_regex, token):
        print(token, 'matches INT')
    elif re.search(floating_regex, token):
        print(token,'matches FP')
    elif re.search(string_regex, token):
        print(token,'matches ID')
    else:
        print(token,'Does Not Match')

Comment: @np05, you've still got errors in your regular expressions that I already pointed out to you but you didn't fix.  And you've introduced new errors for no good reason.  Step back, slow down, and read through your regexs and make sure they are correct both syntactically and logically.  You're very close to a working solution.

Comment: Please accept my apologies for the late response. I did get the code working properly for the input file. I am pasting the working code below.

Comment: import re
import sys
integer_regex = r"^([0-9]+)$"
floating_regex = r"^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+$"
string_regex = r"^([a-z]|[A-Z])|(_|[a-z][A-Z])|[a-z][0-9][A-Z]|[^0-9][.]$"
def processtoken(token):
    if re.search(integer_regex, token):
        print(token, 'matches INT')
    elif re.search(floating_regex, token):
        print(token,'matches FP')
    elif re.search(string_regex, token):
        print(token,'matches ID')
    else:
        print(token,'Does Not Match')
def main():
    fName = sys.argv[1]
    print('processing tokens from ' + fName + ' ...')
 with open(fName, 'r') as fp

Comment: lines = fp.read().replace('\r', '').split('\n')
    #print(lines)
    for line in lines:
        #print(line)
        for token in line.split():
         #print('Inside for')
         processtoken(token)


# --------------------------------------------------
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
# --------------------------------------------------

Comment: Output Generated as below:

Comment: 12345 matches INT
67890 matches INT
afghe matches ID
abcde matches ID
23456 matches INT
0abcd Does Not Match
34567 matches INT
__fred01 matches ID
45678 matches INT
123.456 matches FP
12345a Does Not Match
123. Does Not Match
.456 Does Not Match
ab00cd matches ID
00ab00 Does Not Match

Answer (score 1):

Split the text, use function `isdigit()` to test for `int`, then `try` for `float` and capture `ValueError` for `string`.

```
for m in string.split():
    if m.isdigit():
        print(m, 'Int')
    else:
        try:
            float(m)
            print(m, 'Float')
        except ValueError:
            print(m, 'STR')
```

Output:

```
('12345', 'Int')('67890', 'Int')('afghe', 'STR')('abcde', 'STR')('23456', 'Int')('0abcd', 'STR')('34567', 'Int')('__fred01', 'STR')('45678', 'Int')('123.456', 'Float')('12345a', 'STR')('123.', 'Float')('.456', 'Float')('ab00cd', 'STR')('00ab00', 'STR')
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/Kz8E7A)

Comment: :Thank you for the answer.But I have to use Regex only to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> test = """\
... 12345    67890     afghe
... abcde    23456     0abcd
... 34567    __fred01  45678
... 123.456  12345a    123.
... .456     ab00cd    00ab00"""
>>> def what_is_it(s):
...     print("'{}'".format(s), end=' ')
...     try:
...         as_float = float(s)
...     except ValueError:
...         return 'matches STRING'
...     else:
...         if as_float.is_integer():
...             return 'matches INT'
...         return 'matches FP'
... 
>>> for line in test.splitlines():
...     for token in line.split():
...         print(what_is_it(token))
...     print()
... 
'12345' matches INT
'67890' matches INT
'afghe' matches STRING

'abcde' matches STRING
'23456' matches INT
'0abcd' matches STRING

'34567' matches INT
'__fred01' matches STRING
'45678' matches INT

'123.456' matches FP
'12345a' matches STRING
'123.' matches INT

'.456' matches FP
'ab00cd' matches STRING
'00ab00' matches STRING
```